# How to create Dynamic User Control in Page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

```
<% for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
               {
                   cami = i;
                   cami++;
                   //DataBind();
                    %>
            <cam:CamControl ID="Cam1" CamID=<%# dcami(cami)  %> runat="server" />
               <% } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this great [3-part post](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx) about dynamic controls. There's also a [follow-up post](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2008/04/23/truly-understanding-dynamic-controls-by-example.aspx) with downloadable example code.